# Is this a bug in the Java regexp implementation?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match the string `iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl` against the regexp `([a-zA-Z|_])?(\w+|_|\.|-)+(@\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})?\.yang`.

The expected result is `false`, it should not match.

The problem is that the call to `matcher.matches()` never returns.

Is this a bug in the Java regexp implementation?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld{
    private static final Pattern YANG_MODULE_RE = Pattern
            .compile("([a-zA-Z|_])?(\\w+|_|\\.|-)+(@\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})?\\.yang");

     public static void main(String []args){
        final Matcher matcher = YANG_MODULE_RE.matcher("iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl");
        System.out.println(Boolean.toString( matcher.matches()));
     }
}
```

I'm using:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b15, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Replace `\w+` with `\w`. But a more efficient regex will look like `"[a-zA-Z_]?[\\w.-]+(@\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})?\\.yang"`

Comment: Why should it match when your string ends with .xsl and your regex .yang?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi It shouldn't, OP says the expected result is `false`. Instead, the program never terminates.

Comment: yea just noticed :) Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You can also try using *possessive* quantifier which will never allow to reuse already matched part, even while backtracking. Try with `(\\w+|_|\\.|-)++` (notice additional + at the end).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pattern contains nested quantifiers. The `\w+` is inside a group that is itself quantified with `+`, which makes it hard for the regex engine to process non-matching strings. It makes more sense to make a character class out of the alternation group, i.e. `(\\w+|_|\\.|-)+` => `[\\w.-]+`.

Note that `\w` already matches `_`. Also, a `|` inside a character class matches a literal `|` char, and `[a|b]` matches `a`, `|` or `b`, so it seems you should remove the `|` from your first character class.

Use

```
.compile("[a-zA-Z_]?[\\w.-]+(?:@\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})?\\.yang")
```

Note that you may use a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) instead of a capturing one to avoid more overhead you do not need as you are just checking for a match and not extracting substrings.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ar3pss/1) (as the pattern is used with `matches()` and thus requires a full string match, I added `^` and `$` in the regex demo).

Comment: +1. The regex engine in Java isn't fantastic - I've run into situations like this reasonably frequently where you have to "think" a bit more about the regex in Java than say, Perl.

Comment: Thanks for optimization hints. Now it behaves as expected.

Comment: This answer provides improvement to the regex in question, but it lacks a yes/no with an explanation to the "real" question. Is it a bug? Could it have been prevented by the engine? Or is this normal for any engine? How long would it take for the method call to return? I guess, [Runaway Regular Expressions: Catastrophic Backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) would be a good start.

Comment: @xehpuk It is not a bug. NFA engines are prone to catastrophic backtracking when fed with inefficient patterns. I already explained the weakness of the OP pattern. *How long would it take for the method call to return?* does not make much sense, the answer is from several minutes to ages, we never know how long it may take to recover from CA, if at all possible.